# Feed aggregator using hbase. How to design the schema?

Tags: schema, feed, hbase

I am working on a project involving monitoring a large number of rss/atom feeds. I want to use hbase for data storage and I have some problems designing the schema. For the first iteration I want to be able to generate an aggregated feed (last 100 posts from all feeds in reverse chronological order).

Currently I am using two tables:

```
Feeds: column families Content and Meta : raw feed stored in Content:raw
Urls: column families Content and Meta : raw post version store in Content:raw and the rest of the data found in RSS stored in Meta
```

I need some sort of index table for the aggregated feed. How should I build that? Is hbase a good choice for this kind of application?

Question update: Is it possible( in hbase) to design a schema that could efficiently answer to queries like the one listed bellow?

```
SELECT data FROM Urls ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 2):

Peter Rietzler answer on hbase-user mail list:

> Hi
>
> In our project we are handling event
>   lists where we have similar
>   requirements. We do ordering by
>   choosing our row keys wisely. We use
>   the following key for our events (they
>   should be ordered by time in ascending
>   order):
>
> eventListName/yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS-000[-111]
>
> where eventListName is the name of the
>   event list and 000 is a three digit
>   instance id to disambiguate between
>   different running instances of
>   application, and -111 is optional to
>   disambiguate events that occured in
>   the same millisecond on one instance.
>
> We additionally insert and artifical
>   row for each day with the id
>
> eventListName/yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS
>
> This allows us to start scanning at
>   the beginning of each day without
>   searching through the event list.
>
> You need to be aware of the fact that
>   if you have a very high load of
>   inserts, then always one hbase region
>   server is busy inserting while the
>   others are idle ... if that's a
>   problem for you, you have to find
>   different keys for your purpose.
>
> You could also use an HBase index
>   table but I have no experience with it
>   and I remember an email on the mailing
>   list that this would double all
>   requests because the API would first
>   lookup the index table and then the
>   original table ??? (please correct me
>   if this is not right ...)
>
> Kind regards, Peter

Thanks Peter.